# Python script with -m completes but errors out at very end

Tags: python, virtualenv

I run a script with inside a virtual environment like so:

`python -m cron.nightly.py`

Everything runs fine, but after the last line completes, I get an error:

`/Users/user/.virtualenvs/vrn/bin/python: No module named cron.nightly.py`

Which is fine, except that because the script doesn't exit with a `0` (I think) every time it runs Jenkins marks the job as failed and so I can't tell when the code actually fails or not without looking at each individual console output, which is not ideal to say the least.

If someone could help me explain why I get this error (there's no other traceback) and how to fix it I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cron.knightly.py` is not what you want.  Python modules do *not* end with `.py`.  Just as you wouldn't import `math.py`, you don't run `python -m something.py`.  Change it to `python -m cron.nightly`